# Weird Wifi Issue in Windows

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-10, wifi-configuration, wifi-driver

I have a laptop. Formerly, it had only Windows installed (all worked fine). Then I formated the PC and now I dual boot Ubuntu 14.04.3 with Windows 10, and now I have a problem with wifi in Windows:

If I'm very, very close to the router (less than 2 meters of the router), wifi works well in both system.

But if I'm at more than about 4 meters from the router, wifi only works well in Ubuntu. In Windows, the wireless network looks available but when I try to connect, it doesn't reach connection.

That is, since I formated the PC, in Windows I have a ridiculously low wifi signal reception.

I tried installing all oficials drivers that I found, but it didn't fix it. The weird thing of all this, is that Ubuntu doesn't require me to manually install any additional wifi driver, and it works like a charm. On the other side, Windows requires the installations of officials drivers, that doesn't even work in my case.

Thing that I know/suspect:

1. This is a software/driver problem, not a hardware
   (wifi card) problem, cause before I formated the PC, this didn't
   happen (and in Ubuntu the wifi card still works well).
2. This isn't a Windows **10** problem, cause I tried Windows 8, and 7, and I have the same problem.
3. This isn't a router/AP problem, cause it happens with other wifi networks too.

So, what can I do? Is there a way to extrapolate the wifi driver/configuration of Ubuntu to Windows?

By the way, the wifi card is

- product: AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter
- vendor: Qualcomm Atheros

Comment: What wireless driver are you using?

Comment: I've tried all drivers I found, including Windows generic drivers, and the official Atheros driver (tried many versions, currently using 10.0.0.318)

Comment: In Ubuntu I'm using:
driver=ath9k driverversion=3.19.0-39-generic

Comment: If you have wifi encryption on, turn it off and see if it makes a difference. Also what is the model of the AP?

Comment: Hi, the router is Motorola SBG901. I've tried turning off the encryption,  but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: Do you have a Bluetooth adapter in the computer as well?

Comment: Yes. Actually, the official drivers installer installs both the Wifi and the Bluetooth drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the Power Options in Control Panel.

Chose to edit a Power Profile. There is an option that says "Wireless Adapter Power Savings". Turn it off. Report back with your findings.

PS: Does connecting your Laptop to a power supply help?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. I tried it, but it didn't make any difference. Neither connecting it to the power supply.

Comment: I'll look into any more possibilities.